# Restarting print spooler by using scheduledjob in powershell error

Tags: powershell

I am trying to restart the print-spooler in powershell by the use of scheduledjob and set it to to a daily restart. I get an error message:"Register-ScheduledJob : The scheduled job definition Print-Spooler already exists in the job definition store". What could be the error here? Thanks for the help.

```
  Register-ScheduledJob -Name "Print-Spooler" -ScriptBlock { dir $home\*.ps1 -Recurse | Copy-Item -Destination "
C:\Windows\System32\spool\PRINTERS\"} | Restart-Service -Name Spooler -Force
```

Comment: try to give it a other name? Like Restart-Print-Spooler

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you've already registered this job once, possibly while testing something or figuring out how the command works?

Try getting the existing job:

```
Get-ScheduledJob -Name "Print-Spooler"
```

Further, you can (and should) get rid of the existing one:

```
Get-ScheduledJob -Name "Print-Spooler" | Unregister-ScheduledJob
```

Then you'll be free to create the job again.